# Why can't we view a proposed edit by itself?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I've recently got edit privileges on Stack Overflow, and I've noticed that while we are able to view suggested edits side by side, there is no option to view just the proposed edit on its own.  We can already see the previous version on its own by clicking on the question/answer, but it would be nice if we could be able to take a look at an edit without seeing the big wall of green and red.

Comment: Clarification for future viewers: "Add the `inline` diff tab to suggested edits."

Comment: You can see the suggested edit by itself if you hit the "improve" button, while it's active. Or, if you view the edit itself, if the suggestion was approved.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles: interesting, I thought that it would have shown the original post.  Thanks for that!

Comment: @AwesomePoodles except for audits, where doing so is an instant failure.

Comment: @JanDvorak: eek!  It's good that I haven't needed to look at an audit yet...